# php mysql date.timezone and winter and summer time

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone

I have problems to work right with 
summer  GMT +02:00
and 
winter GMT +01:00
 time in php or mysql

in php.ini date.timezone = 'Europe/Prague'

php and mysql works same, by this way ->

so `strtotime('20120101000000') returns 1325372400`
because strtotime uses local time, meanwhile `strtotime('20120101000000 UTC')` returns right value `1325376000`

but nothing is correct for me, example:
when user get money at 00:30 1.7.2012 and I store it  by strtotime without UTC .... but when I read it in winter time, I will see 23:30 30.6.2012 .... because my GMT +hour were changed

so I try to set local time as UTC and work only with UTC... but it means, that I must change system hours and add to hours (GMT +02:00) now work all fine

but must stop NTP synchronization ... because I need to use time increased by GMT +02:00

could you help me, if exists another brilant solution or how set NTP synchronization with increased by 2 hours

next problem is, that web server says that your time (increased by 2 hours is GMT... but it isn't)

Answer (score 2):

in PHP, you can set the timezone in your script with the function
date_default_timezone_set
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

In mysql, the timezone will default to the system time of your computer/server.  You can learn how to change this in the following way:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Or with mysql, you can do it on a per-query basis with hte following command:

CONVERT_TZ()
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

it is best to deal with timezones by converting all your data to a single TZ, preferably one that isn't susceptible to daylight savings.  GMT or UTC is best practice.  You can convert your query results into the TZ that you want when you need them.  Alternatively, you can us linux timestamps (php: time(), strtotime(), Mysql: UNIX_TIMESTAMP) and then converting those values to human readable strings when you need to.

Hope this helps.